# REST best practice get /articles for guest and for auth?

Tags: android, rest, api

I've read that Get requests should be idempotent.
I'm making an android app with a list of articles. Both guest and authenticated users can view a list of articles, but authenticated also get favorited status.

To make a request idempotent, the authenticated user should request both /articles and a second request to get the favorite status of this article.

How professional developers make these things? What is the best practice?

I see 3 ways:

1. Return a combined result based on the user. for guests favorited: 0, for authenticated if favorited, favorited: 1

GET /articles (statefull)

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"First Article",
      "favorited":1
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Second Article",
      "favorited":0
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "title":"Third Article",
      "favorited":1
   }
]
```

2. Return stateless and make ​additional request to check the favorited status for this article ids if authenticated.

GET /articles (stateless)

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"First Article"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Second Article"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "title":"Third Article"
   }
]
```

if authenticated get favorite statuses for article id 1, 2 and 3
GET /favorites?id=1,2,3

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "favorited":1
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "favorited":0
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "favorited":1
   }
]
```

3. Return stateless. After login user need to request endpoint to get all favorited ids, save them in the local client, and on every item display check from local if post id is favorite. Note some users have 300+ favorited articles

After login get all favorited ids, save in client.

GET /myFavoriteArticleIds

```json
[
   1,
   3,
   5,
   9,
   17
]
```

And then make stateless requests
GET /articles (stateless)

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"First Article"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Second Article"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "title":"Third Article"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using only one API request GET /api/articles. Authorized requests should have the Authorization header value. Based on that the response could be filtered while serializing the result object.

We can have customized responses from API based on the Authorization header.

Refer to Baeldung - https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Answer (score 1):

It would perhaps help to review the definitions of [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) and [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) as found in RFC 7231.  The semantics of GET are *safe*, which means that all of the constraints of *idempotent* are satisfied, and some others.

In summary, safe means *read-only*.

But it doesn't tell you anything about representations, or resource design.

> How professional developers make this things? What is best practice?

Think about how you would design a web site?  One answer would be to have a page for anonymous users, and then a *different* page for administrators (which includes the extra information that the administrators need).  The second page would be locked down so that only authorized users can get at it (which has some interesting implications for [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-3.2)).

The same basic principles hold for an API.

Answer (score 1):

To distinguish the difference between guest and authenticated cases, I would recommend you to use **namespaces** for all APIs.

Ex:
For authenticated users,
/api/articles - list of articles along with favorites 
/api/articles/$article_id - single article information along with favorited time etc

For guest users,
/guest_api/articles - only the list of articles
/guest_api/articles/$article_id - only the article information

Answer (score 0):

Based on the user type, the favorited flag can be returned in response.

User type can be passed a query parameter.

Example: `GET /api/v1/articles?user=guest`